# Issue with length of sparse.matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, xgboost, gbm

I've been trying to train this dataset using `xgboost`. However when I turn it into a sparse matrix there is the following error message;

```
Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) : 
  The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data
```

I'm incredibly confused because the label was derived from the dataset - therefore I don't understand how it is a different length to the sparse matrix.

From what I can tell - the dataframe has 2048 rows, as does the label that was derived from it. However when I turn this into a sparse matrix - 300 rows are added.

Can anyone think of a fix to sort this out?

```
require(xgboost)
require(methods)
require(Matrix)
require(data.table)
require(vcd)
require(dplyr)

train = read.csv("French Ligue 1 train.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
test = read.csv("French Ligue 1 test.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- data.table(train, keep.rownames = F)

sparse_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(Response ~.-1, data = df)

output_vector = sparse_matrix[,Response] == 1

bst <- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix, label = output_vector, max.depth = 4,
               eta = 1, nthread = 2, nrounds = 4, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

Comment: Help page for `sparse.model.matrix` says `'data'`-agrument needs to be a dataframe.

Comment: The data argument is a dataframe in the Sparse.Model.Matrix. The error comes when the label and sparse_matrix are used in the GBM.

Comment: The reason I was making a comment only based on just looking at code is that you have not provided a reproducible example.